# Vue.js bind to a class according to a condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application

With this div declaration:

```
<div v-bind:class="[currentPage === 'help' ? highlight : '']">
```

that I build accordingly to: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax

But the binding isn't working (the class 'highlight' never applied regardless of the `currentPage` value).

I have this model where there is the `currentPage` variable keeping track of the active page:

```
    var vueApp = new Vue({
        el: '#vueApp',
        data: {
            currentPage: 'help',
```

How can I activate the binding of a class on an element, based on the string value of a vue property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the template:

```
<div v-bind:class="[currentPage === 'help' ? highlight : '']">
```

`highlight` is an **identifier**.

Thus, such expression expects that `highlight` is property of the Vue instance/component. It is being evaluated, but since it probably is empty (`undefined`) you get nothing.

Since you want the string, do:

```
<div v-bind:class="[currentPage === 'help' ? 'highlight' : '']">
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vueApp',
  data: {
    currentPage: 'help',
  }
})
```

```css
.highlight { background-color: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="vueApp">
  <div v-bind:class="[currentPage === 'help' ? 'highlight' : '']">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried changing it (adding quotes) but it still doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: It must be something else. Check the updated answer, I have added a demo.